# Groupings in DropdownList

Tags: jquery

I am just starting to learn how to use jquery and i have this code that supposed to be grouping my dropdown items wether it is an "Employee" or "Group", but the output is not what i want. please help. thanks in advance

My Code:

```
var selectControl = document.getElementById('MainContent_DropDownList1');
var item;

var EmployeesGRP = jQuery('<optgroup/>');
var GroupsGRP = jQuery('<optgroup/>');

EmployeesGRP .attr('label', 'Employees');
GroupsGRP .attr('label', 'Groups');

jQuery('option', selectControl).each(function (i) {
    item = jQuery(this);

    if (item.attr("class") == 'Employees') {
        item.wrapAll(EmployeesGRP );
    }
    else {
        item.wrapAll(GroupsGRP);
    }

});
```

the RESULT is:

```
Employees
  Employee number one
Employees
  Employee number two
Groups
  Group number one
Groups
  Group number two
```

INSTEAD of:

```
Employees
  Employee number one
  Employee number two
Groups
  Group number one
  Group number two
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use .appendTo() instead of .wrapAll()

```
var selectControl = $('#MainContent_DropDownList1')

var EmployeesGRP = jQuery('<optgroup/>', {
    label:'Employees'
}).appendTo(selectControl);
var GroupsGRP = jQuery('<optgroup/>', {
    label:'Groups'
}).appendTo(selectControl);

jQuery('option', selectControl).each(function (i) {
    var item = jQuery(this);

    if (item.hasClass("Employees")) {
        item.appendTo(EmployeesGRP );
    } else {
        item.appendTo(GroupsGRP);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Nsm5s/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
item.wrapAll(EmployeesGRP);
```

you need to do this:

```
item.appendTo(EmployeesGRP);
```

Wrap all will wrap EmployeesGRP around each item in the set of matched elements, since you are using a each loop here. So, instead of wraping each time, you can just append the items.

Comment: will not work http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Nsm5s/2/ because then the group elements are not added to select.

Comment: Just wondering, how come it worked for the OP then! He's getting the output, right?

Comment: thank you @palash i used appendTo just like you suggested and added codes from other responses and it worked. :)

Comment: Anyways @ArunPJohny, with one line code, this should work http://jsfiddle.net/Nsm5s/3/